# Оптимизированный запрос к базе данных из нескольких таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть 3 таблицы (условно). Первая - таблица с пользователями, вторая и третья - таблицы с данными пользователя, в них на одного пользователя может быть несколько строк.

Я хочу получать одним запросом сразу все данные из всех таблиц, делаю я это вот таким образом:

```
SELECT users.id,users.email.users.username,2table.data, 3table.data, FROM users INNER JOIN 2table ON users.id = 2table.user JOIN 3table ON 3table.user = users.id AND users.id = 1;
```

Проблема заключается в том, что количество данных из второй и третьей таблицы перемножается, то есть если во второй таблице есть 3 строки на данного пользователя, а в третьей есть 4 строки, то в итоге я получаю 12 строк вместо семи. Могу ли я как-то исправить эту проблему, или решить задачу по другому?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: смотря что это за данные у вас в двух других таблицах. если хотите их склеить в строку, то можете использовать GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: А в каком именно виде вы хотите получить данные из дочерних таблиц ? Помните, что на выходе у нас строго прямоугольная таблица без вложенностей. Как представить эти поля data когда их много и не понадобится ли потом кроме поля data доставать из тех таблиц еще какие нибудь колонки

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы сначала писались данные из 2 таблицы, а там где должны быть данные из 3, были NULL, а потом наоборот, данные из третьей, а там где данные из второй - NULL

Comment: тогда сделать union all таблиц 2 и 3 с теми самыми null. что то вроде `select user, NULL as data1, T2.data as data2 from table2 UNION ALL select user, T3.data as data1, NULL from table3` а потом это в виде подзапроса join'ить к основной таблице